# Using Cauchy's Integral Theorem to solve $\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{(z-1)^2}$, where $\gamma$ is $|z|=3$ (taken counterclockwise)

Tags: complex-analysis

I have$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{(z-1)^2}\ \ \ \ \ \gamma: |z|=3 $$

Can I use Cauchy's integral theorem? I don't think I can, since $z=1$ lies in the interior of $\gamma$. I've solved the integral explicitly by substituting $\gamma(\theta)=3e^{i\theta}$, and then $u=3e^{i\theta}-1$ to get the integral as $0$. But my question is more on the usage and applicability of Cauchy's theorem in this case.

Comment: Cauchy's residue theorem is exactly for the case where a pole is within the region bounded by a curve.

Comment: You're right. But since I got the integral as $0$, and the integrand not being holomorphic/analytic in the interior of the contour I was in doubt of the applicability of Cauchy's integral theorem. As the answer says, I think it's just a coincidence

Comment: For any integer $n\gt 1$ the function $\frac 1{(z-a)^n}$ is the derivative of the function $\frac 1{1-n} \frac 1{(z-a)^{n-1}}$, so the integral over any closed path that does not pass through $a$ is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct; since there is a singularity, pole, whatever $z = 1$ might be called, enclosed by your contour, you cannot apply Cauchy's integral theorem. For Cauchy's integral theorem to apply, no such points can be enclosed in the contour.

At least that's how I learned it; I'll add the grain of salt that I'm just past that bit in my own complex analysis course this semester.

But that said I do feel that the fact that it equals $0$ is just a coincidence; that is, Cauchy's integral theorem doesn't state that the integral is $0$ ***only*** under those circumstances. That it, it can be $0$ under other circumstances, but if the conditions necessary for the theorem do apply, *then* it *will* equal $0$.

If that makes any sense.

---

**Edit:**

On realizing a potential ambiguity, to summarize what I feel is meant by "Cauchy's integral theorem" and how I'm referring to it: for a closed contour $C$ in a domain in the complex plane, where no holes in the domain or singularities of a function $f(z)$ are enclosed, then Cauchy's integral theorem claims

$$\int_C f(z)dz = 0$$

Comment: Right, that's what I thought. Thanks!